Вопрос по PostgreSQL+Django
Есть база данных  PostgreSQL (подключённая к админке) в базе (предполагаются) помимо всего прочего ссылки на аудиофайлы, хранящиеся в облаке, от туда (предполагается) будут подгружаться в тг бота и на сайт, целесообразна ли такая схема? Аудиофайлы будут регулярно добавляться, поэтому задеплоить их вместе с приложением вроде как будет затруднительно

Ну выглядит как то, что и нужно делать: не хранить файлы в PostgreSQL, а хранить путь до них - URL или путь в файловой системе. Обсуждалось в Как хранить файлы в базе PostgreSQL?

Спасибо, вы мне очень помогли
